# Does a 2010 volkswagen jetta 2.5 have a timming belt or timing chain or both

Tags: engine

Does this 2.5 volkswagen  jetta se 2010 have a timing chain or timing belt or both. And need to know how to time it

Comment: If you're working on your own car, do yourself a huge favor and buy the definite repair manual: http://www.amazon.com/Volkswagen-Jetta-A5-Service-Manual/dp/0837616166

Answer (score 2):

I believe the engine in question is a straight 5 from vw range.

It has a timing chain and not the belt, A engine cannot have both.

Comment: My car has both - *kind of*. It's a 2003 Passat 2.8 l and it has a timing *belt* in the front that keeps the intake cams in time with the crank, and *chains* in the back to keep the intake and exhaust cams in time with each other. It's not called a "timing chain," but a "cam chain." This had me terribly confused when I went to change the belt until I realized it has both.

Answer (score 0):

The engine has a timing chain, instead of belts. The only belts present in the jetta engine are for the alternator and the compressor, not for timing !

Comment: Hope you know there are also timing belts for camshafts!

Comment: I know , but for this particular engine there are chains .

Comment: Yes, your answer though correct seems to be little generic, could you rephrase it.

Comment: Is it looking fine now ?

Comment: Awesome! looks good.